# Why do lightnings generated by a tesla coil also move upwards?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current, lightning

I was recently watching some videos of Tesla coils, and the behavior of the rays caught my attention. In the picture below, you can see how the coil is emitting lightnings, some of them towards the ground but many other in just random directions through air.

I understand that the coil reaches really high voltages, which cause dielectric rupture of the air, making it to conduct electricity. However, the only near positive charged conductor is the ground, why don't all rays follow just a path towards the ground where $\Delta V$ should be biggest? why do some rays move upwards where there is nothing more than air (and distant air regions shouldn't be conductive) ?
Also, where is the intensity going? The flux of charges just seem to disappear at some point in air, what happens with those electrons?

[image]